# Showing disabled CTAs

Tags: lists, cta, disabled

What are the pros and cons of showing disabled CTAs?

For example, if there is a list of options but some of these options are shown, yet disabled.

I can see the user being confused/frustrated about seeing the option yet not being able to interact with it.

Comment: Will they be enabled under any circumstances?

Comment: The pros and cons compared to what? Are you talking disabled vs visible, or disabled vs enabled w/ validation?